# Only show loader for requests that take longer than x ms

Tags: angularjs, http

I've got a loader but I only want to show this loader for requests that take a bit more time than just a route switch for example. So I want to start a timer or something similar to see if `x` ms has gone by, and if it passes that time then show the loader.

I'm using this http interceptor to check for requests:

```
core.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$timeout', 'globalStates', function ($q, $timeout, globalStates) {

    var xhrCreations = 0,
        xhrResolutions = 0;

    function isLoading() {
        return xhrResolutions < xhrCreations;
    }

    return {
        request: function (req) {

            xhrCreations++;

            $timeout(function() {
                globalStates.set('isRequestActive', isLoading());
            }, 500);

            return req;
        },
        requestError: function (err) {

            xhrResolutions++;

            $timeout(function() {
                globalStates.set('isRequestActive', isLoading());
            }, 500);

            return $q.reject(err);
        },
        response: function (res) {

            xhrResolutions++;

            $timeout(function() {
                globalStates.set('isRequestActive', isLoading());
            }, 500);

            return res;
        },
        responseError: function (err) {

            xhrResolutions++;

            $timeout(function() {
                globalStates.set('isRequestActive', isLoading());
            }, 500);

            return $q.reject(err);
        }
    };
}]);
```

As you can see I've added a timeout that waits `500ms` before setting the `isRequestActive`, this kinda works but not always. If I quickly switch between views for example then the loader will flicker a bit so this solution is far from optional.

How can I time a request and show the loader after `x` amount of time?